# Failed to get the parameter with Vue-Router in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have 2 routes with `vue-router`, one of them receives a parameter `id`.

```
{ 
    path: '/sale/', 
    name: 'other',
    component: ComponentA,
},
{ 
    path: '/sale/option/:id', 
    name: 'close-sale',
    component: ComponentB,
},
```

it turns out that the redirection is done with code directly, making in `ComponentA`

```
this.$router.push({ name: 'close-sale', params: {id: this.id}})
```

When I do this, it redirects me to the path named `close-sale`, but inside the path I get the id to load some data of the following form

```
data(){
   return {

      id: this.$route.params.id
       ....
   }
 },
  mounted (){
    axios.get('...'+this.id). // undefinied this.id
 },
```

But I always return undenifed for the value of id.

How could I get this id if in the url it is not shown? I hope I have understood

Comment: You can try `this.$router.push({ name: 'close-sale', params: {id: 2}})` and see if the URL is `/close-sale/2`. If it is not - may be there is another redirection somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I tried but I still get the same result ... push removes the URL this is so?

Comment: If your URL is not `/close-sale/2` even with my suggestion - then somewhere something is doing another PUSH / REPLACE. Check your route guards. Also, keep in mind that it is better to use computed value for the route parameter because it will catch reusing the same component with different param - while `data` is initialized only once, at the component creation.